# How to pass value to read variable with pipe (stdin) in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I read a lot about passing piping stdin to bash read function, but nothing seems to work for my bash version!!

GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

I have a bash script that in some point asks the user "yes/no" with variable CONTINUEQUESTION:

```
echo "Do you want to continue? (yes/no):"
read CONTINUEQUESTION
tmp=$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<$CONTINUEQUESTION)
if [[ "$tmp" != 'y'  &&  "$tmp" != 'yes' ]]; then
                echo "Aborting because of input '$CONTINUEQUESTION'"
                exit
fi
```

I would like to pipe a "yes or no" to this question without user input!
Yes i know i could use expect, but i don't prefer it in this case.

So i tried several things:

```
CONTINUEQUESTION='yes'
echo $CONTINUEQUESTION | ./myscript.sh
```

Aborting because of input ''

```
./myscript.sh <<< "$CONTINUEQUESTION"
```

Aborting because of input ''

...and many other, nothing worked!?

O.k. now I did a bit revers thinking and find out that the below line causes the problem with the pipe...because when i remarked it out all the below answers are working just fine, but not when this line is executed:

```
running=`ssh root@${HOSTNAME} 'su - root -c "/bin/tools list | grep \"system running\"" 2>&1'`
```

But, i need this line before the read! What do i need to reverse the 2>&1????

My script look like this and is working without this try to over come the user intervantion:

```
LIST_FILE_NAME=$1
STILL_RUNNING=0

running=`ssh root@${HOSTNAME} 'su - root -c "cat '$LIST_FILE_NAME' | grep \"system running\"" 2>&1'`
if [[ $running =~ .*running.* ]]; then
        STILL_RUNNING=1
        echo "NODE $NODE running stop before continuing."
fi
if [ $STILL_RUNNING -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Aborting system was still running!"
        exit 1
fi

echo "Do you want to continue? (yes/no):"
read CONTINUEQUESTION

tmp=$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<$CONTINUEQUESTION)
if [[ "$tmp" != 'y'  &&  "$tmp" != 'yes' ]]; then
                echo "Aborting because of input '$CONTINUEQUESTION'"
                exit
fi

echo "o.k."
```

4 points:

1. list.log can have a line with "system running" or "system notrunning"
2. if list.log has a line with "system notrunning" than the bash script continue towards the question
3. at the question i never got it right to inject the 'y' or 'yes' so the bash aborts because of input ''
4. i execute this like: ./myscript.sh list list.log (normal way)

This bash runs well if the user interacts at the question!

Thanks for you time!!!

Comment: See also [`yes`(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes)

Comment: You can also replace `if [[ "$tmp" != 'y'  &&  "$tmp" != 'yes' ]]; then` simply with `if [[ "${tmp:0:1}" != 'y' ]]; then` to use substring-extraction to test the first character is not `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this variation as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Do you want to continue? (yes/no): " CONTINUEQUESTION
if [[ $CONTINUEQUESTION != [Yy] && $CONTINUEQUESTION != [Yy][Ee][Ss] ]]; then
    echo "Aborting because of input '$CONTINUEQUESTION'."
    exit
fi
```

Tested with:

```
bash script.sh <<< yes
```

If it doesn't work, show the output of:

```
bash -x script.sh <<< yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Your line

```
$CONTINUEQUESTION='yes'
```

shoul really be

```
CONTINUEQUESTION='yes'
```

I am not sure then that your are feeding stdin with the word 'yes'. You could add an `echo` after the `read` to be sure.

Comment: @user3458191 Didn't that solve your problem? Have you tried already?

Comment: No this didn't solve the problem! It was a type in my question, no in my execution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use heredoc:

```
bash -ex ./myscript.sh << 'EOF'
yes
EOF
```

Search for `Here Documents` in `man bash`.

**EDIT:** Based on comments you can use this `ssh` command:

```
running=$(ssh -t -t root@${HOSTNAME} "grep 'system running' \"$LIST_FILE_NAME\"")
```

Comment: I did tried your answer, but i still get the Aborting msg with input ''!!! Can piping be restricted by command or that tty is not set correct???

Comment: Actually you get prompt message but rest of the script is executed as if input is typed. Make sure you are using BASH only.

Comment: Sorry, i am a real rookie in this! Can you please explain what do you mean by that "Make sure you are using BASH only"??? So, how should the ssh line look like that returns a value to the variable running?? Thanks

Comment: I did run it but i said before the line with the variable running is making the problem, see: _+ NODE_HOSTNAME=caramba
++ ssh root@caramba 'su - root -c "/bin/tools list | grep \"system running\"" 2>&1'_ and you can see the variable running gets nothing and this is correct since no system is running! But then the execution stops due too the -e!
+ running=

Comment: Can you post your complete script in question? Also tell me clearly at what line are you running into problems.

Comment: I edit my question with more details on request from @anubhava

Comment: Although your question was entirely different when I answered it I have provided you a suggestion on how to use `ssh` command. But just to let you know on SO you should post a new question once your previous one has been answered.

Comment: With the changes at the variable running it does work, but i don't like this solution, because i have to change the myscript.sh and this is not an option!!! But thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably didn't understand how SO works then. You ask a question and if you get a working answer then accept the answer. Later if you face different problem then go ahead and ask a different question. Don't expect to solve all your problems with discussion only. Moreover if someone suggests improvements in your not-so-well-written script then it is for your own benefit.